# RxJS: Updating client on each return of parallel http requests

Tags: javascript, http, angular, rxjs, observable

Goal:  Run a number of async http requests in parallel using RxJS and fire callback after each request is returned.

For example:

```
getSomeData() {
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get('/somethingOne.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
        this.http.get('/somethingTwo.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.somethingOne = data[0]
        this.somethingTwo = data[1]
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
}
```

The above code will run the http.get requests in parallel and map the response to json, but on each http response I want a function I created to be called.  Is there any way to pass a callback function to the http requests that are passed to the forkJoin method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that work? Just executing your function in the body of your current selector function. (There might be some syntax errors here, as I don't use ES6). Included two versions depending on how you want to use that function, but the idea is clear : use your `map` selector function to run any logic you want.

```
getSomeData() {
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get('/somethingOne.json').map((res:Response) => {myFunction(res); return res.json()}),
        this.http.get('/somethingTwo.json').map((res:Response) => myOtherFunction(res.json()))
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.somethingOne = data[0]
        this.somethingTwo = data[1]
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: I believe that will work, I just figured RxJS came with a method designed specifically for this purpose.  For example. there are instance methods such as do, doOnNext, filter..etc that seem like they would all work.  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any documentation on the correct method to use for this type of functionality.

Comment: The `do` operator is more intended for performing side-effects (`do` does not allow you to return any value in the stream). Otherwise, the 'correct'  function is a simple map(callback), I don't see what you call 'this type of functionality'. Or you mean you don't want to write `map(callback)` for each and every request?

Comment: The actual intended purpose is to use it with a series of post requests.  After each request is finished I wanted to provide a notification on the front-end of my application, but I don't actually need to do anything with the response object.  For example, make 10 post requests in parallel, and after each one update the front-end with percentage complete (10%, 20%, 30%...etc)

Comment: Then yeah `do` is what you want.